# how to get the list of all tasks along with their status for current dag run in airflow

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Need help to extract the list of all tasks along with their current status [Success/Failed] for the current dag run.
I have a task with a python operator which executes at the end of the workflow. The responsibility of this task is to return the no of tasks executed with the status.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a PythonOperator that read all tasks from the dag_run.

The xcom of task_id="tasks" is :

[image]

```
with DAG(
    dag_id="get_tasks",
    description="get tasks",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    tags=["tasks"],
) as dag:
    start_dag = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")
    end_dag = EmptyOperator(task_id="end")


    def get_tasks(**context):
        dagrun: DAG = context["dag_run"]
        tasks = {}
        for ti in dagrun.get_task_instances():
            tasks[ti.task_id] = ti.state
        return tasks

    tasks = PythonOperator(
        task_id="tasks",
        python_callable=get_tasks,
    )

    start_dag >> tasks >> end_dag
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Airflow API to extract information about your workflows. You can read the Rest API documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.2/stable-rest-api-ref.html). For instance, to list all DAG runs for a specific DAG:

```
http://<AIRFLOW_IP>:8080/api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns
```

After, you can list all tasks for this specific DAG Run:

```
https://<AIRFLOW_IP>:8080/api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns/{dag_run_id}/taskInstances
```

In *Airflow UI >> Docs >> REST API Reference (Swagger UI)* you can access and test the API using Swagger documentation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer...instead of API call i m looking if there are any options available to achieve this using the below options  1. airflow.models.taskinstance or 2. airflow.models.dagrun